# Prove by mathematical induction that $1 + 1/4 +\ldots + 1/4^n \to 4/3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Please help. I haven't found any text on how to prove by induction this sort of problem:

$$
 \lim_{n\to +\infty}1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4^2} + \cdots+ \frac{1}{4^n} =  \frac{4}{3}
$$

I can't quite get how one can prove such. I can prove basic divisible "inductions" but not this. Thanks.

Comment: You can't prove it because it's false for every $n\in \Bbb N$.

Comment: The statement is *wrong* for all $n$. (For example with $n=1$ the claim is that $1+\frac14=\frac54\stackrel?=\frac43$).

Comment: Or maybe the question implies approaches. .

Comment: I think you to need establish the partial sum using induction, then make $n\to\infty$

Comment: @Mob So you want to prove that $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{4^k}\right)=\frac{4}{3}$ by induction? Sure you can use induction, but not on $n$ as it is a free variable. You can prove it by induction (on $m$) by proving the statement $$(\forall m\in \Bbb N)\left(\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{4^k}\right)=\frac{4}{3}\right)$$ but you don't need induction.

Comment: Thanks for all your input. Please in English. I'm new.

Comment: @GitGud : is there a typo in your comment?  I don't see how $m$ is used.

Comment: @StefanSmith It isn't used. There's no typo. It's like proving $(\forall n\in \Bbb N)(1=1)$, just to make it possible to prove it by induction.

Comment: @Mob : you need to find the _value of a finite geometric series_ and take its limit as $n \to \infty$.  Do you have a calculus book?  The answer you seek may be in there?

Comment: @GitGud : I think what the OP needs is a way to find the formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n (\frac{1}{4})^k$ _using induction_, which is standard, then take the limit of that formula as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Amazing how many people don't instantly remember that this was done by Archimedes.

Comment: @StefanSmith I think your interpretation is what it is intended.

Comment: @Michael: You seem to be claiming that Archimedes knew and used mathematical induction in his work.  I certainly don't remember that: to the best of my knowledge the first mathematical induction proofs were given in the late 16th century.  Do you have any evidence to the contrary?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : I suppose I should have written your predictable comment myself, but sometimes I answer fairly quickly.  Obviously I've adapted what I wrote to modern terminology and notation.  The fact that no one had formulated the principle of mathematical induction doesn't mean there were no concrete instances that were precursors.  Archimedes wrote that if in a series each term is $1/4$ of the previous one, except that the last term is $1/3$ of its predecessor, then the sum does not depend on the number of terms.  I'll dig out a reference.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : Thomas Heath's translation of Archimedes' _Quadrature of the Parabola_, Proposition 23. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : I've added Thomas Heath's translation of Archimedes' Proposition 23 to the answer I posted below.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Try 14th Century: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22859/759

Comment: @Double AA: I didn't know about Levi ben Gershon, thanks.  Further searching turns up this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24102/historically-first-uses-of-mathematical-induction, which explores the issue in detail.  It seems to be a matter of contention whether ben Gershon had full-fledged induction or not.  Some say Pascal was the first to do so (that would be 17th century).  I still haven't seen anyone (else) claim that Archimedes used induction.

Answer (score 22):

Archimedes did this (Thomas Heath's translation of *Quadrature of the Parabola*, Proposition 23).  He showed that (expressed in modern notation)
$$
\underbrace{1+\frac14+\frac1{4^2}+\cdots+\frac1{4^n}}+\underbrace{\frac13\left(\frac1{4^n}\right)}
$$
**does not depend on the number of terms.** All you have to do is show that when you go the the next term, the sum doesn't change.  When you go to the next term, you get
$$
\underbrace{1+\frac14+\frac1{4^2}+\cdots+\frac1{4^n}+\frac1{4^{n+1}}}+\underbrace{\frac13\left(\frac1{4^{n+1}}\right)}.
$$
But you have changed
$$
\frac13\left(\frac1{4^n}\right)
$$
to
$$
\frac1{4^{n+1}}+\frac13\cdot\frac1{4^{n+1}}.
$$
The problem then is just to show that those two things are equal.  If you multiply both by $4^n$, then one of them becomes
$$
\frac13
$$
and the other becomes
$$
\frac14+\frac13\cdot\frac14.
$$
It's easy to show that those are equal.

Since the sum does not depend on the number of terms, the sum is just what you get when $n=0$:
$$
1+\frac13.
$$

The method used by Archimedes perhaps cannot be regarded as an instance of mathematical induction, but it suggests at once how to write it as a proof by induction.

**Later note:** Thomas Heath translates Proposition 23 of Archimedes' *Quadrature of the Parabola* as follows:

*Given a series of areas $A,B,C,D,\cdots Z$ of which $A$ is the greatest, and each is equal to four times the next in order, then*
$$
A+B+C+\cdots+Z + \frac13 Z = \frac43 A.
$$

**Still later note:**  Here's what this has to do with parabolas:  Given a secant line to a parabola, draw a line through its midpoint parallel to the axis, [thus](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Parabola_and_inscribed_triangle.svg).

Then draw the two additional resulting secant lines, making a triangle, and construct triangles on top of those two secant lines, in the same way, [thus](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Parabolic_Segment_Dissection.svg).

Archimedes showed that the two small triangles have a total area that is $1/4$ of that of the big triangle.  Then notice that the process can be continued forever, getting the area bounded by the parabola and the first secant line equal to $4/3$ the area of that big triangle.

Comment: Thanks for providing this additional information.  However, after looking carefully at the link provided I don't agree that Archimedes's proof is by induction.  If you look at the algebraic translation given by Heath there is no logical reduction of the $n+1$ case to the $n$ case: the argument for a given parameter $n$ is established directly.  You could choose to recast the argument in inductive terms -- as you have -- but this is not what Archimedes actually says (or needs to say).  In fact, isn't his argument really a version of the telescoping sum approach?

Comment: To me, the clincher that it is not an inductive argument is that, as expressed in my answer, it does not assume the answer in advance for any parameter value.  Rather it *derives* the answer for any given $n$.  (This is better than an inductive argument, it seems to me.)

Comment: Regardless of whether it's an inductive argument (and necessarily one would have to a certain amount of adapting to modern concepts to make it fully such an argument), it instantly suggests (to us who live today) how to do it by induction.

Comment: By the way, the one "ancient" argument I've seen that really does look like an induction to me is Euclid's proof of the infinitude of primes.  Precisely what he does is to assume that there are $n$ primes and produces another one.  Part of the brilliance of this argument is that it seems so isolated in mathematical history, by thousands of years. People don't seem to want to think of Euclid's proof as inductive; rather they want to view it as a proof by contradiction, which is an underselling of it.  I know you'll agree with me on that, at least.

Comment: As I said, I think construing Archimedes's argument as an induction is weakening it a bit.  It is somehow better not to prove something by induction if possible, and Archimedes's argument gives a non-inductive proof.

Comment: Some of Euclid's other arguments might qualify.  His proof that every number can be factored into primes, maybe?

Comment: While we may not completely agree, I think we agree that there are interesting issues here.  Please feel free to explore them by asking an additional question (or questions).

Answer (score 18):

If you want to use proof by induction, you have to prove the stronger statement that

$$
 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4^2} + \cdots+ \frac{1}{4^n} =  \frac{4}{3} - \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4^n}
$$

Answer (score 15):

After subtracting $1$ this is equivalent to $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{64} + \cdots = \frac{1}{3}$. Behold:

[image]

Image taken from [here](http://mrhonner.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/infinite-series-triangle.jpg).

Comment: The lack of objectivity of mathematicians never ceases to amaze me.  This answer is leading on upvotes and it doesn't even answer the question.

Comment: Love the "Behold"! and the big triangle.

Comment: @GitGud That depends on what you consider a proof. This picture can lead to a proof, by induction even.

Comment: @GitGud Aren't mathematicians driven by lack of objectivity? :)

Comment: @QuinnCulver I don't see how it leads to a proof by induction. I can only see it leading to a proof of the limit of the sum, not by induction.

Comment: @GitGud And maybe you're mistaking another phenomenon for a lack of objectivity. E.g. maybe it's just that this is a pretty answer and somehow 'better' than an induction proof. Perhaps it will help the OP more than the objective answer.

Comment: @user17762 It seems so, unfortunately.

Comment: @GitGud By induction, $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4^2} + ...+ \frac{1}{4^n} =  \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{4^n}
$

Comment: @QuinnCulver I'm not denying the usefulness of the picture in establishing the truthfulness of the statement. I'm saying it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @GitGud mathematicians, or people who saw the question in the hot question dropdown and voted for the answer with a pretty picture that they thought they understood?

Answer (score 11):

The below image can easily be made into an inductive proof.

[image]

To be precise, the above image first shows that
$$\dfrac12 + \dfrac14 + \dfrac18 + \cdots = 1$$ and then shows that

$$\dfrac1{2^2} + \dfrac1{(2^2)^2} + \dfrac1{(2^3)^2} + \dfrac1{(2^4)^2} + \cdots = \dfrac13$$
which implies
$$\dfrac1{4} + \dfrac1{4^2} + \dfrac1{4^3} + \dfrac1{4^4} + \cdots = \dfrac13$$

Comment: @AustinMohr There is an induction. In fact, induction is very strongly seen in this picture. Each level, the area of the red square equals $\dfrac1{3^{rd}}$ the area of the green $L$ shaped region. Hence, the sum of the areas of the red squares up-to a certain level equals $1/3^{rd}$ the sum of the areas of the green square up-to a certain level and now letting $n \to \infty$, we get what we want.

Comment: Thanks for the nice picture! But it's not a proof by induction.

Comment: @TonyK As I have mentioned in the above comment, **it is in fact a proof by induction**.

Answer (score 6):

i have a solution, but not seem mathematical induction

$s = 1 + \dfrac1{4} + \dfrac1{4^2} + \dfrac1{4^3} + \dfrac1{4^4} + \cdots$

$\dfrac1{4}s = \dfrac1{4} + \dfrac1{4^2} + \dfrac1{4^3} + \dfrac1{4^4} + \dfrac1{4^5} + \cdots$

$\dfrac1{4}s = - 1 + (1 + \dfrac1{4} + \dfrac1{4^2} + \dfrac1{4^3} + \dfrac1{4^4} + \dfrac1{4^5} + \cdots)$

$\dfrac1{4}s = - 1 + s$

$\dfrac3{4}s =1$

$s = \dfrac4{3}$

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was thinking. I'm at a loss what's meant by *induction* in this context.

Answer (score 3):

The statement of your question is quite confused.  Clearly $1 + \frac{1}{4} + \ldots + \frac{1}{4^n}$ is a quantity that gets larger with $n$ -- you're adding on more positive numbers -- so it cannot be equal to any fixed number.

I think what you want to show by induction is:

> For every real number $a \neq 1$ and every positive integer $n$, $1 + a + \ldots + a^n = 
> \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$.

The setup here is the usual one for the easiest inductions: you check the base case ($n=1$), then for an arbitrary positive integer $n$ you assume that $1 + a + \ldots + a^n = 
\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$.  Then you add the next term -- here $a^{n+1}$ -- to both sides and do at little algebra to show that you get what you're supposed to: here, $\frac{1-a^{n+2}}{1-a}$.  If you can do any induction proofs you can probably do this without much trouble; please try it.

Now:

1) If $|a| < 1$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a^{n+1} = 0$, so

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1+a + \ldots + a^n) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n = \frac{1}{1-a}$.

If you plug in $a = \frac{1}{4}$ you'll get the single identity that I think you're asking for.  This is one of the very first and most important instances of finding the sum of an infinite series.  One often spends much of an entire course studying such things, e.g. towards the end of second semester calculus.

2) Most people would prefer *not* to establish the boxed identity by induction.  This is because of the "kryptonite" inherent in the otherwise superstrong method of proof by induction: you must know in advance what you are trying to prove.  Another standard method will allow you to find the answer without knowing it in advance:

Put $S = 1 + a + \ldots + a^n$.

Multiply by $a$:

$aS =   a + \ldots + a^n + a^{n+1}$.

Now subtract the second equation from the first and note that most of the terms on the right hand side cancel:

$S(1-a) = S-aS = 1 - a^{n+1}$.

Since $a \neq 1$, $1-a \neq 0$ so we can divide both sides by it.  Behold, we have gotten the answer

$S = \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$

that we previously had to know in order to do a proof by induction.

Answer (score 3):

If you multiply $s_n:=1+q+q^2+\ldots + q^n$ with $q$ you get $q+q^2+\ldots +q^n+q^{n+1}$, which differs from $a_n$ by only dropping the first and adding a new last term. More procisely, we find $qs_n=s_n-1+q^{n+1}$, hence (if $q\ne 1$)
$$s_n=\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}=\frac1{1-q}+\frac1{q-1}\cdot q^{n+1}.$$
In your case, you have $q=\frac14$, so the first summand is $\frac43$ and the second tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure if it is possible to prove this using induction but we can do something else.

The sum $\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4^2} + \cdots \frac{1}{4^k}$ can be written as $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{1}{4^n}$. Now $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^k \displaystyle\frac{1}{4^n} = \frac{1-\frac{1}{4^{k+1}}}{1-\frac{1}{4}}$. Now letting $k \rightarrow \infty$ allows us to conclude that $\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4^2} + \cdots \frac{1}{4^k} \rightarrow \displaystyle\frac{4}{3}$

Comment: Oops, sorry, fixed my mistake

Comment: I've deleted that comment.  What you've got now is better, but still in error.  You're saying a sum of _finitely_ many terms is equal to a sum of _infinitely_ many terms.

Answer (score 1):

1. Induction is used to prove statements are true for all natural numbers.
2. You want to prove that this is true only for infinitely large n.

That said, it should be clear that a mathematical induction is inapplicable here.

Trying to use induction to solve this problem is like trying to eat a soup with a fork.

Comment: Good points, but this doesn't actually answer the question (admittedly, the question is unanswerable!) so perhaps would be better off as a comment.

Comment: One can demonstrate the value of the sum of the first $n$ terms by induction, and then take a limit as the number of terms grows.

Answer (score 1):

If you represent 4/3 using binary notation, you get:

1.0101.... (I don't know how to do a 'bar' to show repeating.)

The first 1 after the decimal is read as 1/4 the zero is in the 1/8 place, the next 1 is 1/16, etc. This reads as matching your infinite series.